# How can I use ‘angular-toastr’ in developing a plugin in Grafana

Tags: angular, grafana

Currently i've developing a plugin in Grafana and i need to use notifications like an alert (at top-right corner of screen). There are several packages for this issue (e.g. angular-toastr - https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr). My question is how can I import and use an angular package after install that with nmp install??
I’m trying to use this code:
import toastr from '…/node_modules/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr’
but i encountered with this error:
Plugin Error
Fetch error: 404 Not Found Instantiating http://x.x.x.x:3000/public/plugins/node_modules/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.js

Answer (score 1):

You could include the library in your plugin source code. So if you have a folder structure like the following, ad an 'external' folder to src

```
plugin
     +node_modules
     +src
        +external
```

Now place angular-toastr.js in the external folder and import it into your controller like follows:

`import * as toastr from './external/angular-toastr'`

The problem you're currently having is that you're trying to access a file that doesn't exist, hence your [404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) error. So I'd imagine the path is wrong, but more importantly you probably won't ship your node_modules folder with your plugin, just the dist folder. So when you build your plugin, e.g. with grunt which is what we use, the required library will get copied into you dist folder and will be available as you're now using relative paths.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I create 'external' directory in 'src' folder and copy 'angular-toastr' to that and import like as you say in above. then I use toast.error function for show a notification, but there is one error: toastr.error is not a function

Comment: Is the external folder getting copied to your dist folder?

Comment: Yes, both external folder and angular-toastr.js file copied in dist

Answer (score 0):

This is my folder structure:
[image]

This is my code:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

import kbn from 'app/core/utils/kbn'
import {MetricsPanelCtrl} from 'app/plugins/sdk'
import {Presenter} from './util/presenter'
import {Styler} from './util/styler'
/* eslint-disable import/no-webpack-loader-syntax */
import './css/main-panel.css!'
/* eslint-disable import/no-webpack-loader-syntax */
import * as toastr from './external/angular-toastr'

const panelDefaults = {
  valueMeasurement: 'Avg',
  valueShow: {
    show: false,
    fontSize: '22px',
    format: 'none',
    decimals: '2'
     // fillColor: 'rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)',
 },
  nullValue: {
    nullValueTo: 'N/A',
    nullValueBGColor: 'rgb(128,128,128)'
  },
  tooltipOpt: {
    showName: true,
    showVal: false
  },
  thresholds: '',
  colors: ['#299c46', 'rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)', '#d44a3a'],
  notifications: {
    direction: ['success', 'warning', 'critical'],
    warningNotify: {
      activation: false,
      notifyTitle: ''
    }
  },
  sensorDraw: {
    drawModel: 'Square',
    marginTop: '2',
    marginRight: '2',
    marginBottom: '2',
    marginLeft: '2',
    drawModels: ['Square', 'Circle'],
    circleRad: '60',
    SquareWidth: '120'
  }
}

export class MulStatPluginCtrl extends MetricsPanelCtrl {
  constructor ($scope, $injector, linkSrv, alertSrv) {
    super($scope, $injector)
    _.defaults(this.panel, panelDefaults)

    this.events.on('init-edit-mode', this.onInitEditMode.bind(this))
    this.events.on('data-received', this.onDataReceived.bind(this))
    this.events.on('render', this.onRender.bind(this))
    // this.events.on('data-error', this.onDataError.bind(this))
    // this.events.on('panel-initialized', this.render.bind(this))

    this.alertSrv = alertSrv

    // this.formatter = new Formatter(this.panel, kbn)
    // this.fetchdata = new FetchData(this.panel)
    // this.drawer = new Drawer(this.panel)
    this.presenter = new Presenter(this.panel, kbn, this.alertSrv)
    this.styler = new Styler(this.panel)

    this.aggregations = ['Last', 'First', 'Max', 'Min', 'Sum', 'Avg', 'Delta']
    // this.PubData = {}
    // this.data = {}
    this.measurements = {}
  }

  onDataReceived (dataList) {
    // this.seriesList = seriesList
    this.Sensors = dataList
    this.render()
  }

  onRender () {
    // this.sensor2.crrVal = this.fetchdata.getCurrentVal(this.dataRaw, 2)
    // this.formatter.call(this.sensor2)
    // this.render()
    this.presenter.call(this.Sensors)
    this.styler.call(this.Sensors)
    // console.log('my test console.log')
    toastr.error('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!')
  }

  onInitEditMode () {
    this.addEditorTab('Options', 'public/plugins/rahyaft-mulstat-panel/options.html')
    this.unitFormats = kbn.getUnitFormats()
  }

  onEditorSetFormat (subItem) {
    this.panel.valueShow.format = subItem.value
    this.refresh()
  }

  invertColorOrder () {
    var tmp = this.panel.colors[0]
    this.panel.colors[0] = this.panel.colors[2]
    this.panel.colors[2] = tmp
    this.render()
  }

  invertNotifDirectionOrder () {
    var tmp = this.panel.notifications.direction[0]
    this.panel.notifications.direction[0] = this.panel.notifications.direction[2]
    this.panel.notifications.direction[2] = tmp
    this.render()
  }

  onColorChange (panelColorIndex) {
    return color => {
      this.panel.colors[panelColorIndex] = color
      this.render()
    }
  }

  tooltipRender () {
    //
    // toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!')
    // console.log('my test console.log')
    // this.refresh()
  }

  link (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    // this.masterDiv = elem.find('#rahMulStatMainDiv')
    // this.$panelContainer = elem.find('.rahyaftstat2m-panel-val-container')
    // this.$panelContainer.addClass("st-card");
    // this.$panelContoller = ctrl;
  }
}

MulStatPluginCtrl.templateUrl = 'module.html'
```